# github web UI with wrong "files changed" reported during creating PR merge from release into master

Tags: git, github, git-merge

In our project, we have done this many many times. But this time it is wierd. When trying to create a PR to merge release branch into master for deployment, instead of reporting less than 100 files changed, the github web UI thinks 500 files changed. And many of the file diff are wrong.

master branch is used as the branch build for production deployment. release branch is used for QA build.

For example, file foo.java has not been changed for months, and exists with same history in both branch. But the PR thinks master does not have the file, and try to add it. Even stranger, if I do the reverse PR, from master into release. Now the github files changed thinks the release does not have the file.

Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Github UI only shows output of underlying `git` commands. If you do same thing locally on your computer - fetch and pull both branches and show diff between branch `release` and `master` do you see same diff?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the diff of the two branches locally, you could determine what has changed:

- either the case of the file (uper/lowercase)
- or the permission (755 instead of 644)
- or eol characters (end of lines, when someone still had `git config core.autocrlf` set to true when committing)

If it is a cross-merge issue, a better option is:

- fetch from the original "upstream" repository to update the upstream `master` branch: `upstream/master`
- rebase your PR branch on top of upstream/master
- `git push --force` said PR branch (rebased)

Comment: Thank you. I suspect it's still a cross merge issue. Have a work around below.

Comment: @jay.m Then I have a better option: see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer, I will try that. I am not very good at using rebase, it often confused me with conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understand why github does it, but I have a work around. The work around is creating an intermediate branch from release branch and use it to merge with master first and then create PR with master as base.

```sh
git checkout release
git pull
git checkout -b test/master-to-release
git merge --no-commit master
git commit -m'test/master-to-release created branch from release. merge with master. use master for beam files. use release for the rest'
git push
```

At this point, create a PR for test/master-to-release with maser as base, then the PR shows only files changed in release correctly.
For the same branch, when create a PR with release as base, it then only shows the files changed from master. 
Thus test/master-to-release is an intermediate branch used to solve conflicts and provide a clean branch base to merge with master or release.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have also had this problem before where the files changed on the git web ui is different from the `git diff` on my localhost. I also had to checkout a new branch as a workaround for this issue.